# selenium error list indices must be integers or slices, not WebElement

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scrape src in the picture below and print all of them

[image: Target]

This is my code

```
contentPage = driver.find_element_by_id("J_DivItemDesc")
detail_url = contentPage.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")
for i in detail_url:
    print (detail_url[i].get_attribute("src"))
    i = i + 1
```

and it has the error like below

```
Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.
    print (detail_url[i].get_attribute("src"))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not WebElement
```

I've tried several ways but any of them works. I want to fix them, but I don't know how to do.

Thank you for your kindness in advance. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

You are itself iterating over list items, not over in a range of list length. So instead of

```
for i in detail_url:
    print (detail_url[i].get_attribute("src"))
```

use

```
for i in detail_url:
    print(i.get_attribute("src"))
```

Or to iterate using a range:

```
for i in range(len(detail_url)):
    print(detail_url[i].get_attribute("src"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you tried to get element from array detail_url using non integer index .The value of i in your case will be WebElement,because in this structure(for i in detail_url) we  get element .Also you don`t need to use i=i+1 when you do for loop(this is its work)
If you want to use integer for look up the right way is:

```
    for i in range(len(detail_url)):
        print (detail_url[i].get_attribute("src"))
```

Other possible solution is too loop through elements directly using :

```
for i in detail_url:
    print(i.get_attribute("src"))
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case `i` is not an index but a WebElement. You need to implement this loop to make it work:

```
for i in detail_url:
    print (i.get_attribute("src"))
```

or (if you want to use indexes):

```
for i in range(len(detail_url)):
    print (detail_url[i].get_attribute("src"))
```